# Is the "pattern" attribute in OpenAPI Specification redundant?

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-upload, swagger, openapi

- I have defined the `uploadFile` endpoint in an OpenAPI YAML definition, which lets a user upload files to the server.
- I have passed the `pattern` attribute with value `^(?!.*\\.(exe|sh)$).*$` regex, which makes sure that `.sh` or `.exe` files must not be uploaded.
- I have generated the `spring` code for the same from Swagger Editor, and run it in IntelliJ. But somehow user can upload files having `.sh | .exe` extension.

#### uploadFile endpoint in OpenAPI specification

```yaml
/uploadFile:
    post:
      summary: Upload a file to the server
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                files:
                  type: array
                  items:
                    type: string
                    format: binary
                    pattern: "^(?!.*\\.(exe|sh)$).*$"
      responses:
        200:
          description: File successfully uploaded
        400:
          description: Bad Request.
        500:
          description: Internal server error.
```

#### The generated code for the `uploadFile` endpoint:

```java
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadFilePost(@Parameter(in = ParameterIn.DEFAULT, description = "", required=true,schema=@Schema(pattern="^(?!.*\\.(exe|sh)$).*$")) @RequestParam(value="file", required=true)  MultipartFile file) {
        if(file==null)
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("No files.");

        String filename = file.getOriginalFilename();
        System.out.println(filename);

        if (filename.matches("^(?!.*\\.(exe|sh)$).*$"))
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(filename);


        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("No executesble-script files are allowed.");

    }
```

- I want that whenever the user sends an executable file, the API should not accept it.
- We have here `schema=@Schema(pattern="^(?!.*\\.(exe|sh)$).*$"))` annotation present in the params in spite of that I have to explicitly run `String's matches()` method for the file-name against the regex.
- So what the use of that `pattern` attribute in an OpenAPI definition?

Answer (score 3):

`pattern` is the regex pattern for the *value* of a string parameter/property. For example,

```yaml
type: string
pattern: ^abc
```

means "any string that starts with *abc*".

`pattern` is not related to file names in file uploads. OpenAPI Specification does not have a way to limit the file names in file uploads.

What you can do instead:

- Document the acceptable file names in the `description` of the endpoint or its request body schema.
- Use [`x-` extensions](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/openapi-extensions/) to include arbitrary metadata in your OpenAPI definition, such as the acceptable file names or file extensions. However, in this case you may also need to modify your code to process your custom extensions the way you want.