# Validate multipart form filename

Tags: multipartform-data, openapi, jsonschema

I have an openapi schema defining a file upload but I know it is incorrect. However, the examples on the site for 3.1.0 aren't very complete.

I want to have a valid schema for a multipart form which accepts a file, but also validation for the *filename*.

I have something below which doesn't make sense as it is validating the content of the file rather than the filename, but asides from the `pattern` field, I believe this is the correct way to define a file upload as part of a multi-part form;

```json
"/my-endpoint": {
  "post": {
    "requestBody": {
      "required": true,
      "content": {
        "multipart/form-data": {
          "schema": {
            "type": "object"
            "properties": {
            "file": {
              "description": "binary file including file extension",
              "type": "string",
              "pattern": "filename\\.ext",
              "format": "binary"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I modify this to validate both a file upload and perform a pattern validation on that file's filename?

Comment: Does this answer your question -- [Is the "pattern" attribute in OpenAPI Specification redundant?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75607343/113116) Recap: OpenAPI does not have syntax to limit the file names for file uploads.

Comment: "OpenAPI does not have syntax to limit the file names for file uploads". That answers it, thank you @Helen